# Windows 10 appear stuck when network change

Tags: networking, windows-10

Windows 10 1909 (but also previous versions) has a strange behavior when network change (wifi connection changed, ethernet cable attached, vpn connected): for 10-20 seconds i can't start new applications, open new explorer windows, navigate to new sites. After that time every action I tried in the meantime are executed all at once.
How can I find the culprit or the program that cause this?

Comment: try with the resource monitor. and check e.g. CPU if anything spikes when you do the network change...

Comment: seems to be Kaspersky Internet Security. I need to investigate more..